# What do ".subsurface()", ".convert_alpha()", and "%" do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite, alpha

I'm trying to learn Pygame, and the tutorial that I am following has a section explaining how to animate sprites. It gives me a sprite sheet that has 8 images measuring 128x128 each, while the entire sheet measures 1024x128.

Then it presents the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env_python
import pygame, sys
from pygame.local import *

pygame.init()

ZONE = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))

pygame.display.set_caption("Game Zone")

RED = (255,0,0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

counter = 0
sprites = []

sheet = pygame.image.load("spritesheet.gif").convert_alpha()
width = sheet.get_width()

for i in range(int(width/128)):
    sprites.append(sheet.subsurface(i*128,0,128,128)) 

while True:
    pygame.display.update()

    ZONE.fill(RED)
    ZONE.blit(sprites[counter],(10,10))

    counter = (counter + 1) % 8

    clock.tick(16) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

The tutorial is very vague about what those lines do, so I wonder:

1. What does `sheet.subsurface()` do? And what do those four parameters stand for? (I believe that the third and fourth are referring to the individual images' width and height.)
2. What does `.convert_alpha()` do? The tutorial says it "preserves transparency," but I found it strange since I already used images with transparent backgrounds before and none of those needed such conversion.
3. What does `%` do? I already know that `/` stands for division, but the tutorial never explained `%`.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to jump right into Pygame without getting a good understanding of Python first. I'd recommend looking through the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) for more info on operators like `%` ("modulus").

Comment: Have a look at the [pygame docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) too.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know there were python and pygame docs that I can actually understand (the few ones I tried explained basic things with concepts I still haven't learned)...
 
Also, sorry for not knowing "modulus". It happens that the tutorial I'm following never explained it, and the other tutorials I found out in the internet gave it other uses (like substituing strings), I decided to put this in the question since I was already going to ask it...

I still don't understand what ".subsurface" do. Pygame docs says that it creates a "child" surface, but why would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subsurface` gets you a surface that represents a rectangular section of a larger surface. In this case you have one big surface with lots of sprites on it, and subsurface is used to extract the pieces from that surface. You could also create new surfaces and use blit to copy the pixels, but it's a bit easier to use subsurface and it doesn't need to copy the pixel data.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface

Suggested search: [pygame subsurface](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pygame%20subsurface)

`convert` and `convert_alpha` are both used to convert surfaces to the same pixel format as used by the screen. This ensures that you won't lose performance because of conversions when you're blitting them to the screen. `convert` throws away any alpha channel, whereas `convert_alpha` keeps it. The comment that you see refers to the choice to use `convert_alpha` instead of `convert`, rather than a choice to use `convert_alpha` instead of nothing.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert

Suggested search: [pygame convert_alpha](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pygame%20convert_alpha)

The '%' operator isn't a Pygame feature, it's just Python's "modulo/remainder" operator. In this case it's used to make the `counter` variable loop repeatedly through the values 0 through to 7 and back to 0 again.

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Suggested search: [python percent sign](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=python%20percent%20sign)

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk about subsurface(). Assume you have 1,600 images you want to load into the program. There are two ways to do that. (Well, more than two, but I'm making a point here.) First, you could create 1,600 files, load each one into a surface in turn, and start the program. Alternately, you could place them in one file, load that one file into a single surface, and use subsurface(). In this case, spritesheet.gif is 128 pixels high, and contains a new image every 128 pixels.

The two ways basically do the same thing, but one may be more convenient than the other. In particular, opening and reading a file has a small performance cost, and if you need to do this 1,600 times in a row, that cost could be significant.

My understanding of a child surface is that it's basically a Pygame Surface, but defined in terms of a parent surface; if you changed the parent Surface, any child surfaces would be changed in the same way. However, in all other ways, it can be treated as a regular surface.